# How to replace a special string character pattern using python in csv file

Tags: python, csv, modifier

I'm new to python and I'm trying to edit a .csv by replacing the comma "," with the semicolon ";". With the code I have now, I can change a comma by any character except the semicolon. Do you have any idea how I can do this? Thanks in advance for your help. :)

```
import re

#open your csv and read as a text string
csv_path = r"test.csv"
with open(csv_path, 'r') as f:
    my_csv_text = f.read()

find_str = ","
replace_str = "''"

#substitute
new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)

#open new file and save
new_csv_path = r"new_test.csv" # or whatever path and name you want
with open(new_csv_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_csv_str)
```

I still have the same problem. Nevertheless, thank you all for your answers. I can bring some precision on the subject.

The idea is to replace the commas by semicolons without changing the structure. But the fact of made this change create a conflict because for the .csv file the separation between cell is done via comma.

I tried with the two other examples that also create a change in the structure ... . I can't upload the pictures to show you examples because the site shows me : "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server". So I put links directly to the photos on the ImgBB site.

[Screen Before](https://ibb.co/JndQLtB)

[Screen After](https://ibb.co/D7wkS0n)

I hope this helps you to clarify the subject.
Thanks again

Comment: Try using `replace_str = ` with apostrophe characters enclosing the semicolon character (instead of the double-quotes).

Comment: 1) @dat, that won't work *"replace_str = `;`"  "replace_str = `;`SyntaxError: invalid syntax"*. Double quotes is the way to go. 2) Works for me: `find_str = "," replace_str = ";" re.sub(find_str, replace_str, 'test, test2')  'test; test2'` 3) You will need provide some example data and the complete error message you get. **Add as update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I guess I could have been more clear. Not backtick -- the single quote. ASCII 39. This should work fine: `replace_str = ';'` under python 2 or python 3.

Comment: Just as well as `replace_str = ";"`

Comment: I added somes informations to complet my problem :)

Comment: Per here [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), **do not use images** for textual data. Instead copy and paste the text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code works with `;`:

```
cat semi_colon_test.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8

import re

find_str = ","
replace_str = ";"


with open('semi_colon_test.csv') as f:
    file_text = f.read()
    replaced_text = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, file_text)
    with open('replaced_test.csv', 'w') as r_file:
        r_file.write(replaced_text)

cat replaced_test.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                   
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8
```

You can skip the `re` search and replace by using the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module:

```
import csv

with open('semi_colon_test.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows_list = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        rows_list.append(row)
    with open('replaced_test.csv', 'w') as r_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(r_file, delimiter=';')
        csv_writer.writerows(rows_list)
```

Comment: I added somes informations to complet my problem